# Inherit property from parent class and add attribute to the inherited annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one, java-annotations, hibernate-cascade

I have a derived class MyBusinessBody which extends a parent class BusinessBody.

One field in BusinessBody looks like:

```
public class BusinessBody{
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Trade trade;
  //setter and getter
  ... 
}
```

Now, I want to add another attribute, "**cascade = CascadeType.ALL**" to the annotation @OneToOne, but I don't want to do it inside BusinessBody, rather, I'd like it amended in the derived class MyBusinessBody.java, something like:

```
public class MyBusinessBody{
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  protected Trade trade; //NOTE: I changed the modifier from "private" to "protected", otherwise the IDE shows warning that this field is not used.
  //setter and getter
  ... 
}
```

Will this work?

Comment: Private access modifier is secure your data

Comment: #ide_warning: it should be used in (public) g-/setter!?/ignore/deactivate it ;) #cascade: it depends: how you want to map (uni-/bi)?; and who should cascade whom? (but i think all (4?) cases should be possible)